# .limit(1) on asset field loop is effecting another loop on same page

Tags: assets, forloop

I have an Asset field where the first image is used as a big 'feature' and then the rest are used as support further down the page.

When I add .limit(1) to the for loop for the 'feature' image it effects the for loop further down the page by also only showing 1 image.

This is my code...

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('abstractionProjects').type('abstractionProjects').all() %}
{% for projectPanels in entries %}

    Some HTML...

    {% for asset in projectPanels.projectImages.limit(1) %}
      <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">
    {% endfor %}

    Some HTML.....
    More HTML...

    {% for thumbs in projectPanels.projectImages.offset(1) %}
      <div>
          <img src="{{ thumbs.url('projectPageThumbs') }}" alt="{{ thumbs.title }}">
          <a href="{{ thumbs.url('projectPageFullSize') }}" class="gallery"></a>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

    More HTML...

{% endfor %}
```

If I remove the .limit(1) from the first loop all the images are shown in both loops :/

Help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `projectPanels.projectImages.first()` or `projectPanels.projectImages[0]` to access the first item.

Comment: Thanks Aran... now I get "Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a string variable ("3")."  when trying both .first() and [0]

Comment: Try accessing the first asset without the for loop. `<img src="{{ projectPanels.projectImages[0].url }}" alt="{{ projectPanels.projectImages[0].title }}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is actually the intended behaviour, and one that changed when going from Craft 2 to Craft 3. You can read more about it in the [Changes in Craft 3 article in the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#element-queries). `projectImages` in this case which is an Asset field (I assume), returns an ElementQuery when you access it with `projectPanels.projectImages`. The field doesn't automatically return a new model when accessed, it returns the reference to the one and same query.

The workaround is to either reset the parameters you need to reset, like `limit()` in this case, or use clone as described in that article.

Ie, either something like this:

```
{% for asset in projectPanels.projectImages.limit(1).all() %}
   ...
{% endfor %}

{% for thumbs in projectPanels.projectImages.limit(null).offset(1).all() %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Or,

```
{% for asset in clone(projectPanels.projectImages).limit(1).all() %}
   ...
{% endfor %}

{% for thumbs in clone(projectPanels.projectImages).offset(1).all() %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Have stumbled on this quite a few times myself alreadym, it's a bit confusing. Hope this helps though. :)